# How to save all the frames from a mp4 video using gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer, frames, gst-launch-1.0

I want to know the syntax or command on how I can save all frames as jpg images from my 20 mins mp4 video using GStreamer. With FFmpeg I am able to do it but not sure about gst-launch-1.0

Comment: Save it as what?

Comment: @FlorianZwoch a jpg image

Answer (score 1):

Should be something along these lines:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=<video_file> ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=%05d.jpg
```

Comment: jetson@jetson-desktop:~/Downloads$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=toy_cars.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=images/img%05d.jpg
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Opening in BLOCKING MODE
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261

Comment: That sounds like a jetson specific error. Probably it wants to use a hardware decoder which is failing for some reason.

Comment: WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0: not negotiated
Additional debug info:
gstbasetransform.c(1415): gst_base_transform_reconfigure (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0:
not negotiated
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
qtdemux.c(6073): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)

Comment: Do you know how I can fix it? Can you take a look please?

Comment: You try setting decoder manually. Replace `decodebin` with `qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! `. If the video codec is H.264. Else you need to adjust and hoe you have the decoders installed. If you want it on hardware you needs to investigate more. I dont have a jetson.

Comment: Thanks I tried the same and it worked.
Do you know how to replicate the same using CPP code of Gstreamer and Deepstream?

Comment: Look at the `gst_parse_launch()` function. It is a helper to create a pipeline from these launch pipelines. For the rest check the Gstreamer tutorial.

Comment: What if I want to extract frames from two videos simultaneously?